# AutoGenerate a column in Room Database based on a Condition

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

Let's say that I have a Room database with 3 columns, A,B and C. I want that when the database would be created, the column C will be filled with values by default that will satisfy some conditions over the existing data columns A and B, like for example, I want column C to hold 0 for a row where A

How can I achieve such a thing?

Comment: You write, when the database will be created, A, B and C will be created. But then you write about conditions of the **existing** columns A and B. Can you please clarify the question? Are A and B already existing or created with C together?

Comment: @romulus Let's say that the condition is that C will be 0 if A<B, else it will be 1. Columns A and B will be populated. After this, I want C to be populated by the condition, that is, each row of C is filled up according to the condition taking same row's A and B.